# Is there a way of adding an input in pinescript to allow a true/false tick box for a barcolor change

Tags: pine-script

The following is part of the code for an indicator and I'm trying to allow the user to switch this element ON/OFF in the Inputs Tab rather than the style tab. Can anyone assist please?

```
    // Bar Color

    int signal = (long) ? 1 : (short) ? -1 : 0
    bool colorSet = false
    color col = na
    col :=
   close > open and low < open and high > close ? color.yellow : close < open and low < close and 
   high > open ? color.yellow : na

    //  valuewhen(signal != 0, signal, 0) ==  1 ? 
    //  valuewhen(signal != 0, signal, 0) == -1 ? close > open and low < open and high > close ? color.yellow 
    : close < open and low < close and high > open ? color.yellow : na : na

    if signal != 0
        col := na
    barcolor(col, title="Possible Trend Change")
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use this

```
var bool b = input(true, "On/Off", type=input.bool)
```